# Setting up the dispatcher and CDN integration with AEM 6.x - Steps and Best Practices?

Tags: apache, webserver, aem, dispatcher

We need to setup a new AEM 6.x project that on production makes use of benefits of a CDN (like Akamai) and a dispatcher module within a Apache HTTP Web Server.
So this query is about asking for what point to begin at and what are the steps involved in the same? Also what are the best practices to take into consideration while going for the same?

Comment: Start here - https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher.html

Comment: A colleague created some [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/AshokkumarTA/aem-dispatcher-tips-tricks) on dispatcher tips from personal project experience.

Answer (score 3):

It entirely depends on how you want to configure your systems, both dispatcher and CDN cache have their own best practices outlined in documentation (available over internet).

There are two types of setup I have seen so far -

1. Cache everything on dispatcher as well as CDN
2. Cache everything on dispatcher but do not cache HTML on CDN (so effectively you are caching images, CSS, JS but no HTML)

---

### Cache everything on dispatcher as well as CDN

- After first hit everything gets cached
- Simple setup
- Cache cleanup is complex, you will need your own logic to associate with dispatcher flush to flush CDN cache. Refer to [Akamai Connector](https://www.velir.com/blog/2014/07/09/easily-integrate-akamai-your-adobe-cqaem-instance-velir-s-akamai-connector)
- There are complexities to related content flush, while publishing the content from author to publish AEM identifies the related content and sends the activation for same. This needs to happen for CDN flush as well.
- Complete flush of CDN cache is not an option, it takes a lot of time to complete.

---

### Not caching HTML on CDN

- Has all the advantages of above approach
- For libraries and image assets implement selector based versioning (AEM ACS Commons provides that for ClientLibs, you could implement your own logic for ASSETS url rewriter that adds last modifiedDate as selector to asset call, and your rendering servlet takes care of selector management)
- With proper expires header set on Assets and clientLibraries you will not have to worry about explicit CDN cache management
- Pages when activated with new assets and/or library will refer to updated selectors and get cached on dispatcher. When a call is made to that page, CDN caches the libraries and assets and page refers to CDN version of same. Assets and libraries are independent and are reflected independently with the Pages.
- Based on TTL the outdated resources gets cleared of from CDN

There may be additional steps required in getting the above steps working, what I have outlined is the high level approach. You will need to follow the security, SSL, domain modeling, and other configuration guidelines as specified in the dispatcher documentation and CDN setup. For few you could refer to AKAMAI blog [here](https://community.akamai.com/community/web-performance/blog/2015/06/22/adobe-cq-aem-akamai-integration-best-practices)

Comment: Could you possibly share steps to setup the Apache HTTP dispatcher and a free/trial license based CDN; need it to do hands on and gain insights to the steps involved.

Comment: Steps for dispatcher are same as the one specified in AEM documentation. As for free CDN you could use AWS Cloudfront, amazon is offering free 1 yr limited account, https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

Comment: We are also not planning to cache HTML in our case as CloudFront doesn't support SSI/ESI as Akamai does. And I think to make selector-based versioning for assets work we will need to do a bit more. The additional step I have added to my list is that whenever an asset got activated/replicated we have to clear the cache on the dispatcher for all the pages referencing that asset otherwise CDN will continue to get the old HTML from the dispatcher pointing to the old assets and hence your client will see the stale content.

Comment: Also, ACS Commons Dispatcher Flush Rules (https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/dispatcher-flush-rules/index.html) don't have this functionality. (https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/issues/912)